# Find duplicates mysql up to number digits

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for duplicates in a Google Map table. The problem is the latitudes are slightly different and the addresses are slightly different (but I can tell they're duplicates). Therefore, I'd like to get all records where the latitude is the same up to 4 places after the decimal point.  How can this be done?

Something like:

```
Select * from googlemap
having count(len latitude > 4) > 1
```

Fields:

`point_id`, `entry_id`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `address`, `city`, `zipcode`, `state`, `field_id`, `icon`, `supplier_id`

Sample data from first answer:

```
'9', '51.5124', '9,557,885,908,964,1353,2145,2947'
'17', '32.7921', '17,19,94,2652'
'37', '32.7799', '37,101'
'54', '34.0953', '54,165'
'71', '42.3582', '71,2724'
'73', '25.7660', '73,125'
'100', '25.7906', '100,106'
'112', '25.7870', '112,378'
'113', '32.7114', '113,316'
'114', '25.7689', '114,140'
'129', '25.7708', '129,138,142'
'148', '25.7518', '148,155'
'156', '25.7710', '156,171'
'172', '35.6563', '172,175'
'174', '35.6559', '174,184'
'194', '48.8677', '194,261'
'195', '48.8661', '195,210,248,268'
```

Comment: You *could* just check if `ABS(g1.latitude - g2.latitude) < 0.0001` (and ditto for longitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT ROUND(latitude,4), GROUP_CONCAT(point_id SEPARATOR ',')
FROM googlemap
GROUP BY ROUND(latitude,4)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: what's the group_concat part doing?

Comment: @jeff - it's just giving you the ids of the records that have that latitude.

Comment: I thought that was it but I don't think that's working correctly i checked to see other id's but can't see them...

Comment: @jeff  - not sure I understand what you mean by "i checked to see other id's but can't see them".

Comment: i've added sample data from your query to my original answer

Comment: I think i see what it's doing sorry... I think your answer will work, i noticed that in the query i added point id but it wasn't returning the dupe id rows as well...

Comment: @jeff - may want to look at nnichols answer as well.  Depending on what you are doing, his method may work better.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM googlemap g1
INNER JOIN googlemap g2
    ON TRUNCATE(g1.latitude, 4) = TRUNCATE(g2.latitude, 4)
    -- AND TRUNCATE(g1.longitude, 4) = TRUNCATE(g2.longitude, 4)
    AND g1.point_id < g2.point_id
```